# Dusk isn't loading correct .env

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to get Dusk to using my .env.dusk.local settings, but it continues to use only what is in .env.

I've read that it might be a read/write issues with the .env file, though it doesn't seem locked down at all.

I'm using Laragon on a Windows 10 machine with Laravel 5.8 and PHP 7.1.3.

Comment: can you check what is the environment variable in .env file, local or production

Comment: In the .env its set to local.  I've tried to override it using both an .env.dusk.local, and .env.dusk.testing.  All the settings are the same, but the database name changes, so that's what I'm trying to update.

Comment: can you make sure the cache is clear by running php artisan config:clear

Comment: Just tried that again, still no luck.

Comment: are you serving dusk using homestead, of yes you need to use php artisan serve --env=dusk.local